# Directory /ETC has been moved! — Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, boot, grub

I made a bad move by moving my /etc directory to Dropbox in hopes to sync two computer enviroments. After moving the /etc directory any sudo commands responded with "Who is this UID 1000?".

Basically I killed my user and kill all booting. Now I can't event boot up my system.

PLEASE HELP. Is there any bootable tool or method through GRUB command-line during boot process that I can gain access to my files.

I just need to run

mv /home/user/Dropbox Files/etc /etc
Is there anyway I can do that through the GRUB command-line during bootup? Standard terminal commands don't seem to work.